# Installed Java SE and Java EE - setting up JVM

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

I've installed Java SE and now I want to install Java EE. But after the JDK installation the command `java -version` on the command line returns:

`Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)`

and that is strange for me because it works even if I deleted in environment variables `JAVA_HOME` (which points correct path to JDK folder) and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` from `Path` variable.

**EDIT:**

This is my `PATH` variable:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card`

Answer (score 1):

[Java EE is a set of components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) rather than a separate JVM.

When you removed the variables, did you restart your command prompt?  If the command prompt which you typed `java -version` was still open, it would still work fine until the window was closed.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. Yes I close and open new command prompt and still it works fine.

Comment: Please provide the contents of `echo %Path%`

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. Java EE sdk is independent, and you'll still need the JRE to launch java apps (including your application server, like Glassfish). Later you'll create applications which will be deployed to application server.